# Autofill Html text and password fields

Tags: html, autofill

Chrome automatically fills the UserName as well as password field i tried using hidden fields and autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="false" but still same.
I want to stop autofill but keep autocomplete for fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: you can use `autocomplete="off"` in form tag
`<form autocomplete="off">`